# Maybe a quick fix but I'm having problems with overflow-x:hidden after I publish on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a site deployed and everything was fine in testing but since I deployed and checked out the site on mobile the overflow-x is showing on mobile. Heres a link:

https://www.bolderclimbingcommunity.com/

let me know if you've had a similar problem/ tell me what im doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First, temporarily remove all overflow-x that you put in the body and containers then download a [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pesticide-for-chrome/bblbgcheenepgnnajgfpiicnbbdmmooh) to check overlapping layout on mobile, do it on dev-tools.

Comment: how do you check the overlapping layout with this tool?

Comment: I tried getting rid of all instances of overflow-x and tried to put them back in various spots while testing on mobile. no dice the overflow is still there